# Do downvotes stop you from getting a "Good Answer" badge?

Tags: support, badges

I noticed that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965472/what-should-a-software-engineer-web-start-by-learning-erlang-haskell-python/1965518#1965518) of mine has 25 upvotes, but I didn't get a Good Answer badge for it.

I thought it was because it was a community wiki answer, but after searching meta a bit, I found out that CW votes count towards the badge.

The answer has a score of 25, but it has two down votes (+27, -2). Do the downvotes cancel out the badge?

Or does it just take time for the badge to be awarded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just takes time to be awarded. You should still get a Good Answer badge for that.

Comment: Hooray! Not only am I getting a badge, but Jon Skeet answered my question! What a successful night

Answer (score 0):

Any of those types of badges are awarded based on net score, not on upvotes (or downvotes, in the case of Peer Pressure) alone.

As long as your post has hit the threshold at the time the badge-awarding script runs, you'll get the badge. Sometimes it takes a little while for the script to run.